# When does your commander also participate in the battle?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

3 scenarios

1. I have a commander chosen from one of my knights, commanding my army. Does his prowess matter, ie. does he fight in the battle and kill enemy knights?
2. I have a commander who is the player character. Does he fight in the battle?
3. I have a commander chosen from one of my knights, but my PC is one of the highest prowess characters available. He doesn't appear in the "Knights" dropdown to be able to forced into a battle. Does he fight in the battle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### For scenario 1, the answer is "Maybe".

Is your knight-commander also part of the army fighting? Then, yes. Otherwise, no.

It is entirely possible to have a knight who is a commander but is not participating in the battle as a knight. Probably most commonly occurs if you lose a knight early in a war and don't re-raise your troops from a rally point -- you can appoint any courtier as a commander, and if a courtier is an unraised knight, they will not participate in battle.

It is *also* possible for a knight to lead an army while being physically present in another army. How? No clue. Maybe really good messenger hawks.

[image]

### For scenario 2, the answer is "No".

Only knights fight in battle, and since the player character is never a knight, they will not fight. However, Commanders can be wounded, slain, or captured in battle even though they don't fight -- being present is enough.

This is true even in scenarios without knights at all - in which case the message given is "Commander so-and-so was wounded by an enemy soldier" rather than the named knight.

The chance of this is partially based on Prowess, so it's still better to have high prowess if you're leading troops personally.

### For scenario 3, the answer is "No".

As mentioned in scenario 2, only knights fight in battle, and since the player character is never a knight, they will not fight. (They're still in danger, however, and having a high prowess helps mitigate that)

Comment: So prowess is of relatively little importance for the player character, correct? Since they aren't killing enemies directly.

Comment: @Ren Yup. Pretty much the only use I've found is for "Prowess Challenges" inside of events, where success is based on your character's Prowess score.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes it matters and he does, at the end of the battle you can see how many casualties each knight caused in the knights tab of the battle overview.
2. Yes, and he can also be injured or killed in the battle
3. Prowess indicates how good your character is at fighting, e.g. how his chances are winning an individual encounter. However the martial skill determines how good they are at leading a battle. It could be that your PC character is not a knight in your army because of low martial skill.

Comment: Also, character in the army can die in multiple ways, like from starvation during siege/march. (In CK2 character could get scurvy for being in the sea for too long). So, if you value some character just don't knight it, or send as army leader.

Answer (score 0):

**Commander do not score any kills, but they still might get injured.**

If commanders would be able to kill enemies, then their kills would be listed on the "Knights" tab of the battle summary. But unless the commander also happens to be a knight in the same army, they won't be listed there.

However, it is still possible for the commander to get injured in battle. My character once acquired the "maimed" trait during a battle.